# How can I convert a batch file for Daemon Tools to Virtual Clone Drive?

Tags: hard-drive, batch-file, clone

I would like to convert a batch file I used for Daemon Tool Lite for use with Virtual Clone Drive instead. It's important that the drive is loaded properly before the program starts. I have tried myself but so far no luck. Any help greatly appreciated. This is my current Batch file:

@echo off

set mds_file="G:\GAMES\Other Games\WipeoutXL\Wipeout.XL.mds"
set DTLite="C:\Program Files\DAEMON Tools Lite\DTAgent.exe"
set Prg_run="G:\GAMES\Other Games\WipeoutXL\Wipeout2.exe"
@echo off

IF NOT EXIST %mds_file% goto missing_mds
IF NOT EXIST %DTLite% goto missing_DTLite
IF NOT EXIST %Prg_run% goto missing_PrgToRun
echo MDS location    : %mds_file% ok!
echo DTLite location : %DTLite% ok!
echo Program location: %Prg_run% ok!
echo.

:mount_image
echo Scsi virtual drive letter %errorlevel% ok!
echo (Drive letter: D=3, E=4, F=5, G=6, H=7, I=8, J=9, K=10, ...)
echo.
echo Mounting image...
%DTLite% -mount scsi, %scsi_count%, %mds_file%

%Prg_run%

:missing_DTLite
echo Error: Not found %DTLite%. 
goto exit

:missing_mds
echo Error: File not found %mds_file%.
goto exit

:missing_PrgToRun
echo Error: Program to run file not found %Prg_run%.
goto exit

:error_add
echo Failed to add new scsi virtual drive!
goto exit

:error_letter
echo Could not retrieve scsi virtual drive letter!
goto exit

:error_mount
echo Error: Unable to mount image file %mds_file%!
goto exit

:exit

Comment: *I have tried myself but so far no luck.* -- What exactly is the error you're encountering here?

Comment: Well I tried adding lines from the Batch file I found but I keep getting errors like The drive is not ready, or sometimes the game will just start without mounting the disc first. Here is the batch file @Anaksunaman                                                                                                             "C:\Program Files (x86)\Elaborate Bytes\VirtualCloneDrive\Daemon.exe" -mount "%imagefile%" "%drive%"
:loop
if not exist "%drive%\" (
    sleep 1
    goto :loop
    )
xcopy "%drive%\" "%tempfolder%" /e /h /i /r /y